# My android app doesn't work on university wifi

Tags: networking, android, ssl

I've developed an Android app relying on a REST server. The app works great on mobile network and also on my WiFi.

But when I try it at the university, it cannot connect to the server. The connection is an https on the standards ports (which aren't blocked). If I try to load the server URL in chrome it can reach the server.

I don't think it's a code related issue because some other android apps don't work here either. I think it's a firewall rule but what?

When I curl the the address of the server (the same as the android app), it returns correctly. Is it an user-agent filter or something like that ?

I don't know if it can be the cause but I self-signed my ssl certificate. Can it be related ?

What can cause this issue ? Is it a solution on my side ?

Comment: You should ask this question on either the http://android.stackexchange.com or on the http://stackoverflow.stackexchange.com site. Because that might be a problem in the code, because as you said, the URL isn't blocked, there might be a problem in the code itself.

Comment: I come from there and they redirected me here because it's not related to the code. I know that some android app don't work here so I don't think it comes from my code.

Comment: please add this information to your question.

Comment: Would you happen to use a proxy of some sort in the university?

Comment: I don't think, the ip assigned is the same via ifconfig and on external website. Also the only configuration needed is the security access (802.11).

Comment: Did you try talking to your university's network admins? In my experience they are usually ready to help.